# 2D gaussian gradient as a vector quiver plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, vector, gaussian

I am trying generate a vector plot of the gradient of a 2D gaussian function in python, that should look like [this](http://umdberg.pbworks.com/w/page/88516931/Example%3A%20Gradient%20of%20a%20Gaussian):

[image: 2d gaussian gradient]

However, the code I have adapted produces the following. (The gradient of a 2D gaussian should not produce arrows pointing in the directions shown in this plot):

[image]

From a 2D gaussian here:

[image]

Can someone help explain what is at fault with the following code? The main parts are from (a) [2D gaussian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687679/how-to-generate-2d-gaussian-with-python), (b) [splitting gradient array into x and y components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003993/generating-gradient-map-of-2d-array) and (c) [vector quiver plot with arrows](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# define normalized 2D gaussian
def gaus2d(x=0, y=0, mx=0, my=0, sx=1, sy=1):
    return 1. / (2. * np.pi * sx * sy) * np.exp(-((x - mx)**2. / (2. * sx**2.) + (y - my)**2. / (2. * sy**2.)))

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # get 2D variables instead of 1D
z = gaus2d(x, y)

gauss_grad = np.gradient(z) # calculating array of gaussian gradient

nx, ny = 50, 50

x1 = range(nx)
y1 = range(ny)

U = gauss_grad[0] # x component of gaussian gradient
V = gauss_grad[1] # y component of gaussian gradient

print(" Value of U: ", U)
print(" Value of V: ", V)

X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
 
fig, hf = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)) # setting up quiver plot
hf.set_title("Example - gradient of gaussian- every 2nd arrow")
Q = hf.quiver(X1[::2, ::2], Y1[::2, ::2], U[::2, ::2], V[::2, ::2], units='width',
    pivot='mid', scale=0.1, headwidth=5)
qk = hf.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, r'$2d \ vector \ plot$', labelpos='E',
    coordinates='figure')
hf.scatter(X1[::2, ::2], Y1[::2, ::2], color='c', s=0)

plt.show()
            
#plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='Blues')
#plt.colorbar()
#plt.show()
```

Comment: only 1 line in your code  should refer to the chart you need - here `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); Q = ax.quiver(X1, Y1, U, V); plt.show()`, anything else is the problem either of your gradient calculations or with variables used

Answer (score 0):

This was solved, by swapping around the `x` and `y` axes of the 2D gradient output. So that now:

```
U = gauss_grad[1] # x component of gaussian gradient
V = gauss_grad[0] # y component of gaussian gradient
```

output is now:

[image]