# How to replace outliers of 2d array with estimated background values?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, signal-processing

I have one 2D array called `no2` which is related to the other two 2d arrays `sza` and `vza`.

Test data (test.npz, 450 KB) can be downloaded from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pkabce3MGc8dE_H_8XDuVWCgKbmOvmNv/view?usp=sharing).

Here's the overview:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.load('test.npz')
sza = data['sza']
vza = data['vza']
no2 = data['no2']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6))

ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4 = axs.flat

m = ax1.pcolormesh(no2)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('no2')

m = ax2.pcolormesh(sza)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('sza')

m = ax3.pcolormesh(vza)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('vza')

s = ax4.scatter(sza, no2, c=vza, s=1)
plt.colorbar(s, ax=ax4, label='vza')
ax4.set_xlabel('sza')
ax4.set_ylabel('no2')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: overview]

I wanna replace the two high `no2` regions based on the surrounding background or low `no2` values to get something like this:

[image: result]

Because it seems the `no2` relies on the `sza` linearly as shown in the last subplot, I come up with three ideas:

### Curve fit

Using the fitting between `no2` and `sza` with several `vza` bins to calculate the background `no2` for replacing the high `no2` values:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 4, figsize=(12, 6))
ax = axs.flat

for index,bin in enumerate(range(5, 65, 5)):
    mask = (vza>bin)&(vza<bin+5)
    # print(index)
    s = ax[index].scatter(sza[mask], no2[mask], c=vza[mask], s=1)
    plt.colorbar(s, ax=ax[index], label='vza')
    ax[index].set_title(str(bin)+'<vza<'+str(bin+5))

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel('sza')
    ax.set_ylabel('no2')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: relationship]

I tried to fit the curve for one bin (45<sza<50):

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = sza[(vza>45)&(vza<50)]
ydata = no2[(vza>45)&(vza<50)]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=(1, 1e-5, 1))

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.legend()
```

However, it failed to get what I want:

[image: fit]

Is it possible to meet both conditions below?

**- Fit curve and get the background values for high values**

**- Add random noise to the fitted background values (this can run several times to get more real values like the surrounding background values)**

Or any other better methods?

### Gradient

I checked the gradient and hoped it can make the high values more significant:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003993/generating-gradient-map-of-2d-array
grad = np.gradient(no2)
fulgrad = np.sqrt(grad[0]**2 + grad[1]**2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 3))

ax1, ax2  = axs.flat

m = ax1.pcolormesh(no2)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('no2')

m = ax2.pcolormesh(fulgrad)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('no2 gradient')

plt.tight_layout()
```

However, it can only show some outlines:

[image: gradient]

### Image processing

I can't figure out how to replace the high values only and keep the background unchanged using the scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out how to replace the high values with estimated background values.

Just use [dual-tree complex wavelet transform](https://scikit-ued.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/baseline.html#iterative-baseline-determination-using-the-dual-tree-complex-wavelet-transform) from scikit-ued.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skued import baseline_dt

data = np.load('../data/test.npz')

baseline = baseline_dt(data['no2'], wavelet = 'qshift3', level = 6, max_iter = 150)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))

ax1, ax2, ax3 = axs.flat

m = ax1.imshow(data['no2'], vmin=0, vmax=7e-4)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('no2')

m = ax2.imshow(baseline, vmin=0, vmax=7e-4)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('baseline')

m = ax3.imshow(data['no2']-baseline, vmin=0, vmax=7e-4)
plt.colorbar(m, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('no2 - baseline')
```

[image: example]