# How to use SURF in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, surf

I am going to work on a image processing project "currency recognition system " in pycharm. I just want to match the input image with the existing images in the database and show the result(database image name). How can I do this with SURF function. I checked it on internet but didn't get any relevant code. Could you please help me to do this?

Thanks
Chathu

Comment: Your question is very broad and unspecific. You should tell us what you already tried, give us a piece of code you worked on, so we got something to work with. Please consider reading [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your post. You also may want to tag `matplotlib` instead of pycharm (the IDE is irrelevant).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Still I have not started the task. I just need to know that how to use "surf " function to match the database images. If you can help me then that would be great.

Comment: Probably duplicated:<br>
Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175533/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-surfx-y-z-c-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an implementation of Speed Up Robust Features (SURF). You'll be better off using a library like OpenCV for your use case.

Read the [OpenCV docs](http://opencv.org/documentation.html) on how to Install.
[Here's](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) how to use SURF in OpenCV once you're done installing.

Comment: yes That is it. I have already installed the opencv. But I haven't a clear idea to use SURF with matching database images. could you please help me?

Comment: Check the second link. Ping back if you face problems.

Comment: https://opencv.org/documentation.html is a dead link and cv2.SURF has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

SIFT and SURF are examples of algorithms that OpenCV calls “non-free” modules. These algorithms are patented by their respective creators, and while they are free to use in academic and research settings, you should technically be obtaining a license/permission from the creators if you are using them in a commercial (i.e. for-profit) application.

But Good New is ...

It’s also important to note that by using opencv_contrib  you will not be interfering with any of the other keypoint detectors and local invariant descriptors included in OpenCV 3. You’ll still be able to access KAZE, AKAZE, BRISK, etc. without an issue:

```
>>> kaze = cv2.KAZE_create()
>>> (kps, descs) = kaze.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
>>> print("# kps: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))
# kps: 359, descriptors: (359, 64)
>>> akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create()
>>> (kps, descs) = akaze.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
>>> print("# kps: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))
# kps: 192, descriptors: (192, 61)
>>> brisk = cv2.BRISK_create()
>>> (kps, descs) = brisk.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
>>> print("# kps: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))
# kps: 361, descriptors: (361, 64)
```

More Information Get From That Link: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/