# How to obtain 3D colored surface via Python?

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, matplotlib, surface, colormap

How to obtain the following surface via Matplotlib?

It is easy in matlab via:

```
mesh(peaks)
```

It seems matplotlib does not have an exact counterpart of `mesh` in matlab.
the `Wireframe plots` does not have any `colormap` option

[image]

Comment: How mplot3d? http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots ?

Comment: None of them works. I need exactly the same `colormap` being applied on the `mesh` or the `wireframe`

Comment: Do you require a `mesh` or would a `surface` suffice?

Comment: `mesh` not `surface`; Surface plot can be easily implemented via matplotlib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595083/1881610) I found that you can easily do this using `plot_surface` to produce a color mapped surface, and then exchanging face and edge colors:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, shade=False, cmap="jet", linewidth=1)
draw()
surf.set_edgecolors(surf.to_rgba(surf._A))
surf.set_facecolors("white")
show()
```

produces

[image: Final plot]

The disadvantage this solution has over the other one is that the edges do not have smooth, per-pixel colouring, but one single color each.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in 1.5.1. This does:

`surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, shade=False, cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white']))`

`m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(surf.norm)`

`surf.set_edgecolors(m.to_rgba(surf.get_array()))`

Comment: @wilywampa Thanks. Your fix doesn't work for me; but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355410/edgelines-vanish-in-mplot3d-surf-when-facecolors-are-specified) gave me the hint to add the `linewidth` keyword to the `plot_surface` call, which does fix the behaviour.

Comment: If hidden lines behind surface is not desirable, one can use `surf.set_facecolor([0]*4)` instead of `'white'`

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be possible with matplotlib even if it is a bit of a hack:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import art3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
wire = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

# Retrive data from internal storage of plot_wireframe, then delete it
nx, ny, _  = np.shape(wire._segments3d)
wire_x = np.array(wire._segments3d)[:, :, 0].ravel()
wire_y = np.array(wire._segments3d)[:, :, 1].ravel()
wire_z = np.array(wire._segments3d)[:, :, 2].ravel()
wire.remove()

# create data for a LineCollection
wire_x1 = np.vstack([wire_x, np.roll(wire_x, 1)])
wire_y1 = np.vstack([wire_y, np.roll(wire_y, 1)])
wire_z1 = np.vstack([wire_z, np.roll(wire_z, 1)])
to_delete = np.arange(0, nx*ny, ny)
wire_x1 = np.delete(wire_x1, to_delete, axis=1)
wire_y1 = np.delete(wire_y1, to_delete, axis=1)
wire_z1 = np.delete(wire_z1, to_delete, axis=1)
scalars = np.delete(wire_z, to_delete)

segs = [list(zip(xl, yl, zl)) for xl, yl, zl in \
                 zip(wire_x1.T, wire_y1.T, wire_z1.T)]

# Plots the wireframe by a  a line3DCollection
my_wire = art3d.Line3DCollection(segs, cmap="hsv")
my_wire.set_array(scalars)
ax.add_collection(my_wire)

plt.colorbar(my_wire)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An official feature request is underway:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3562

The accepted solution doesn't work when X and Y arrays are not the same size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the current `matplotlib 1.3.1` does not handle such `mesh` plot or further PDF export. `gnuplot.py`[gnuplot.py 1.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot-py/files/Gnuplot-py/1.8/) might be a choice before there is further updates in matplotlib.

Here is an example created via gnuplot:
[image: mesh]

[MayaVI2](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/tips_mayavi2.html) does not support PDF exports but might be another good choice.