# How to remove the hidden lines in a plot_wireframe via matplotlib?

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib

Does the `matplotlib` in python 2.x support hidden line removal?

How can I implement it myself?

This is a further question of another post solved here:
[How to obtain 3D colored surface via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909256/how-to-obtain-3d-colored-surface-via-python)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that by "hidden" you mean lines that are behind surface patches in the view, e.g., behind "hills" in the plot.

Use `plot_surface` instead of `plot_wireframe`:

[image: plot_surface vs plot_wireframe]

I used

```
plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
```

to create the first and

```
plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10, color="white", shade=False, edgecolor="blue")
```

to create the second plot.

If you want to combine this with colormapping the edges, you'll have to use some internals. If you use the `cmap` argument to colormap the surface faces, the source code for `Poly3DCollection.do_3d_projection` eventually calls `to_rgba(self._A)` to calculate face colors. Remap this to edge colors, and you're good to go:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, shade=False, cmap="jet", linewidth=1)
surf.set_edgecolors(surf.to_rgba(surf._A))
surf.set_facecolors("white")
```

produces this plot:

[image: Final plot]

(You might have to call `set_edgecolors`/`set_facecolors` again after the first render pass as `do_3d_projection` might override the values; I ran this in interactive mode and have not checked.)

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I think I was being thrown off by some weird behavior, probably related to a [matplotlib bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5830).

Comment: I ran this with `%matplotlib widget` and `%matplotlib inline`, and it does not seem to work. if cmap is in `plot_surface` call, then `set_edgecolors`/`set_facecolors` has no effect...