# Matlab plot equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plot:

[image]

How can I achieve 3D plot like this for two dimensional array in Python? Say each line presented on the plot above is a single one dimensional array. I looked through matplotlib gallery https://matplotlib.org/gallery/, but there is nothing similar to the plot above.

Comment: How do you do that in Matlab? Probably it is a wider code of diferent plots with `hold on` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how it's done in Matlab. I found aforementioned plot in currently read paper and it looked very "Matlabish".

Comment: There is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751535/colored-mesh-plot-of-a-function-in-python) relating to this.

Comment: I dont think is made in Matlab. However, you could. But you need to write a piece of code that iteratively goes plotting the lines in the position. There is not a inbuilt 1 liner, sorry.